# Can I use the name of a TV serial / movie for my novel

Tags: trademark

I am planning to write a novel in which the name of one of my character is Agent X but I found out that it has been used as a name of a TV serial.

Answer (score 1):

Under US laws: If your use of an existing trademark (not to mention a REGISTERED trademark) can be viewed as "likely to create confusion" among consumers, as to the source and affiliation of your works, then it would be (by definition) a trademark infringement.  In theory, you would need permission from each and every owner of a confusingly similar brand, i.e., in related fields.

However, it is not generally a trademark infringement to write ABOUT existing goods or services and reference their trademarks, especially if your writing clearly disclaims any affiliation or sponsorship.

Comment: Someone might also be rescued by the **Scène à faire** doctrine in this particular fact pattern. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sc%C3%A8nes_%C3%A0_faire